# SSRS- stop content appearing if condition met

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I'm learning reporting services and working with SSRS. I have configured my report but theres 1 thing I'm missing which is annoying me.
I have set my report up in a way that if certain words appear in the description it should colour the text red. This works fine. But now I want to extend this so If the if any of the keywords appear in the description that whole row should not be displayed in the report.
Is this possible to do? If so, how. As I cannot find it and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the detail line to not show, you can set the visibility on the row to the following: Assuming your description column is called "`description`"

Right click on the row (left hand side of the detailed row) and select Row Visibility.. then select "Show or hide based on expression" then click the Fx button and enter something like this

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!description.value,"WHAT")>0 OR InStr(Fields!description.value,"EVER")>0, true, false)
```

Comment: The alternative is to filter out the data in your query (dataset)

Comment: The reason I didn't want to filter it out at data level is because I wanted to keep it for analysis purpose but just not have it on the report. Will try your suggestion hopefully that works.

Comment: the above fails as containst doesnt accept this number of arguements

Comment: You can use the `InStr` function instead, but the general idea here is correct.

Comment: @StevenWhite can you kindly give me a example as I couldn't get it working

Comment: @ssrsnoob please see my edited answer (code) using instr.. that should do that job for you.. of course.. "what" and "ever" are just stuff I made up.. replace those with what you need to search for.. *HINT* when someone gives you a hint at a possible solution, please try and follow through with it..I.E. Google it and you will get your answers quicker..

Comment: @Harry.. great seems to do the trick.. I only asked for an example as I couldn't get it working myself after my own research.. looks like i was missing the > 0 part.. hence the examples help me learn.
I appreciate the help